# How to check if specific button(Keyboard) is pressed - C++

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm creating an application that deals with ASCII characters and their meaning.

There are 2 parts of this program:

1.) List (Entire list of ASCII Decimal, Hexadecimal, Octal, Binary, Character, and description)

2.) User Input (Type OR press specific ASCII character and reveal Decimal, Hexadecimal, Octal, Binary, and description)

Listing will be simple, but with user input of ASCII character, is there a way I can check to see if the user has pressed a button, and if so, what ASCII character it holds?

I could simply use decision making (if-else) and have the user enter the ASCII character, but I think it would be quicker (And cooler!) if they could just press a button.

Sorry if this question disregards requirements, not asking for a code snippet handout.

Comment: It cannot be done in standard c++. You need to access control over your OSs keyboard driver, or use a library to do that.

Comment: Much thanks. I'll be looking into it.

Comment: If you are on windows, `GetKeyboardState` for all keys, or `GetAsyncKeyState` for a single key will do. If you are wanting to make it cross-platform, the library you are using for the UI most likely has something for it.

Comment: And if you are going for a console application without any third party libraries, simply read input from `std::cin`

Comment: Which libraries should I include? With <iostream>, <string> it shows as undefined. Sorry for my lack of knowledge. This concept is new to me and I'm unsure of what to use or the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is expecting something like this. Just get the input and check input is in the printable range. If so print the ASCII number

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        c = 0;
        c = _getch();
        if (c > 31 && c < 127) {
            std::cout << c << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: should use [`std::isprint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) rather than range-checking.